# Three20 wont deploy to device

Tags: iphone, three20, deployment

I followed the "Adding three20 to your project" steps to a tee and having some deployment issues. I can run the iphone app in the simulator without any issue. But when I try to run it on the device i get the following error "___restore_vfp_d8_d15_regs", referenced From:.....

I do believe that it has something to do with my Header Search Paths that I have set. The header search path is currently set to: ../three20/Build/Products/three20

Can anyone tell me what my issue is?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, it is not a header search path problem. It would be a different error message. Try the following:

1. Find out if you are using Admob, I know that it causes problem on iOS4;
2. find out which version of OS you have on your device, make sure you choose base SDK 4.0, and choose deployment version to your device version;
3. then manually build each and every .xcodeproj in three20 lib that have been added to your project with the same base SDK + deployment SDK setting;
4. Then build and run your project on your device
5. If #4 still doesn't work, use GCC LLV instead of GCC and try again.

Hope this helps.